# Debug on visual studio 2019 community not recognize user

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have problem with using `Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()` on my new website in C# visual studio 2019 community.

My SQL query for recognize `Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()` below :

```
SELECT * FROM dotable WHERE UPPER(douser) IN ('" + Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower() + "');
```

if I do debug on visual studio 2019 community ( S.O. Windows 10, developer project and **IIS Express Microsoft Edge** ) the output is :

```
SELECT * FROM dotable WHERE UPPER(douser) IN ('');
```

Instead if try out on web browser **Internet Explorer 11** ( S.O. Windows 7 ) the output is :

```
SELECT * FROM dotable WHERE UPPER(douser) IN ('123459');
```

On visual studio 2019 community ( developer project ) I have settings :

```
windowsAuthentication = enabled
anonymousAuthentication = enabled
```

How to do resolve this ?

Please, can you help me ?

Comment: `anonymousAuthentication = disabled` ?

Comment: @vasily.sib I have tried but login credentials are required and when insert  credentials user not authorized